# Laravel: Get monthly sales，year by year

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get month sales including 0 sales, for current year and past 3 years.

I need the output like:

| Sales | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Total ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 12 | 0 | 10 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 11 | 1 | 63 |
| 2020 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 8 | 20 | 6 | 70 |
| 2021 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 9 | 5 | 8 | 3 | 59 |
| 2022 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 8 | 15 | 7 | 11 | 65 |

The query I have so far, how to I group the sales by month first, then only group by current year and past 3 year. Also how to I get the total sales for each year?

```
$sales = Member::select(
            DB::raw('year(created_at) as year'),
            DB::raw('month(created_at) as month'),
            DB::raw('sum(price) as price'),
        )
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->startDate, $request->endDate]) // filter sales by date
        ->where(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), '>=', "2019-01-01")
        ->groupBy('year')
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

return $sales;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupBy collection method on the result of get.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby

```php
$sales = Member::select(
            DB::raw('year(created_at) as year'),
            DB::raw('month(created_at) as month'),
            DB::raw('sum(price) as price'),
        )
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->startDate, $request->endDate]) // filter sales by date
        ->where(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), '>=', "2019-01-01")
        ->groupBy('year', 'month')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(['year', 'month']);

foreach($sales as $salesPerYear) {
   foreach ($salesPerYear as $salesPerMonth) {
      $salesPerMonth->price;
      ...
   }

}
```